# ADT: <VM does not provide monitor information>

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adb, adt

When I debug my Android programs on a real device (HTC One S) using Eclipse ADT the last element in the stack trace is always "<VM does not provide monitor information>". This means I don't get to know what part in my code caused the exception. Is there any way to get this information?

Example stack trace:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalStateException)) 
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    Choreographer.doCallbacks(int, long) line: 563  
    Choreographer.doFrame(long, int) line: 529  
    Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run() line: 719 
    Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 615   
    Choreographer$FrameHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92   
    Looper.loop() line: 155 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5454    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1029 
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 796 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: My guess is that you have Eclipse set up to break on unhandled exceptions. In that case, you need to run past the point of the exception, allowing the exception to be logged to LogCat.

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right! Can you please make this an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Eclipse set up to break on unhandled exceptions, Eclipse breaks *before* LogCat gets a chance to log stuff.

The main options that I am aware of are:

- Do not break on unhandled exceptions in the first place, or
- Press the "Run" option in the debug toolbar to proceed past Eclipse's breakpoint, so LogCat can log the exception